# Collect a hash of arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

```
h = {1=>[1,2,3], 2=>[4,5,6]}
new_arr = []
h.each_value {|arr|
  new_arr.concat(arr)
}
```

This works, but what's a more ruby-like way to do it?

All values are arrays but the elements of each array should not be modified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How's about this?

```
h.values.flatten
```

Comment: Definitely the simplest solution :)

Comment: You can use `h.values.flatten(1)` if you're worried you may flatten something you shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

You can use reduce:

```
h.values.reduce(&:+)
```

Comment: I can't seem to find where the reduce method is defined. And what is the & syntax?

Comment: Enumerable is the module that almost all enumerable data structures (Hashes, Arrays, Sets and more) mix in in ruby.  You should study it more than almost any other part of the ruby language ;) http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html  The `&:+` syntax is `&` (proc), followed by the Symbol `:+`, which is a way of specifying a method invocation, instead of actually passing a block.  In this case `+` is invoked on each element in the `values` array.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly cryptic

```
h.flat_map(&:last)
```

Slightly verbose

```
h.flat_map{|_, value| value}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the array of hash value, use Hash#values.

```
new_arr = h.values
```